# Worldbuilding doesn't show up in the "StackExchange" dropdown on my browser anymore

Tags: bug

Is there something wrong with my browser settings?

I can't find it in the search bar. I had to go over to the proposal in Area 51 to find it.

EDIT: As you can see; when I put "world" in the search bar, WorldBuilding doesn't show up anymore.

[image: StackExchange dropdown with the word "world" in the search bar without any results]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doesn't show up for me either, but you can add it to your "favorites" bar.

[image]

Click the edit link (circled above), then type in "Worldbuilding" in the box that shows up. Then hit the save button to save the changes. You can then add it to your favorites if you would like. I'm guessing that because this is a private beta, it doesn't show up in the standard list of SE sites. For that you will have to wait for it to enter public.

Comment: i did that yesterday, it was there, now it isnt... when i add it again it shows for the time i dont refresh the page... than its gone again...

Comment: Are you sure you're clicking the save button when you add it to favorites?

Comment: blame on me... the save button i did not hit. Everytime i added it the save button scrolled out of view. If you add the "hit save" in the Answer i acept it and can close this.

Comment: @Fulli There you go.

Answer (score 2):

Sites in private beta are not visibly linked to the rest of the network.  If you check your network profile page you won't see it there either, even though you do have an account here and it is tied to your others.

When the site goes into public beta all of this should work as expected.

Comment: it was visible for the last few days on the search engine for me. Thats why i was confused about the fact it isn´t anymore.

Comment: It was?  Huh, ok -- maybe the site chooser isn't as tied to the network profile as I thought.  (You might want to edit your question to add that you've seen it work before.)